# How to strip out \r\n in between a quoted string in between tabs when rows are also delimited by \r\n?

Tags: ruby, regex, csv

In Ruby 2.1.3, I have a string representing a title such as in a tab delimited csv file format:

```
string = "helloworld\r\n14522\tAB-12-00420\t\"PROTOCOL \r\nRisk Effectiveness \r\nand Device Effectiveness In \r\Ebola Candidates \"\tData Collection only\t\t20\t"
```

I want to strip out the "\r\n" only in the tab delimited portion that starts with Protocol so I can read a complete title as "PROTOCOL Risk Effectiveness and Device Effectiveness In Ebola Candidates"....I want the end result to be:

```
"helloworld\r\n14522\tAB-12-00420\t\"PROTOCOL Risk Effectiveness and Device Effectiveness In Heart Failure Candidates \"\tData Collection only\t\t20\t"
```

If I don't do this, trying to read it in via CSV truncates the title so I only end up reading "PROTOCOL" and not the rest of the title.

Keep in mind there may be an indeterminate number of \r\n characters I want to remove within a title (I'll be parsing through different titles).  How do I accomplish this?  I was thinking a regular expression might be the way...

Comment: Does the csv module actually truncate the field on `\r\n` ? Can't you tell it not to ? Otherwise, just strip linebreaks when you get the values.

Comment: You can also just to a replacement before you pass the string to CSV, since it doesn't contribute to delimiting.

Comment: Yes, using CSV.parse automatically truncates the title to "Protocol".  I'm reading in multiple rows that are delimited by newlines, so telling it not to truncate on newline would mean I can't parse the rest of the data.  Each column of data (such as the title) is separated by tabs.

Comment: Are you passing in each row independently to CSV?

Comment: The CSV resides in dropbox.  I make a call to get it via dropbox API and it comes back as a string.  This string is the input for CSV.parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a newline (outside of quotes) is treated as a delimiter,
you could use this regex to isolate quoted fields then replace any `\r?\n` just
within that field.

You would then pass the string into the CSV module.

There are 3 groups that together constitute the entire match.
1. Delimiter
2. Double quoted field
3  Non-quoted field

Would need a replace-with-callback function implementation.
Within the callback, if group 2 is not empty, do a separate replace of all CRLF's.
Catenate goup 1 + replaced(group2) + group 3, then return the catenation.

```
 # ((?:^|\t|\r?\n)[^\S\r\n]*)(?:("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"(?:[^\S\r\n]*(?=$|\t|\r?\n)))|([^\t\r\n]*(?:[^\S\r\n]*(?=$|\t|\r?\n))))

 (                             # (1 start), Delimiter tab or newline
      (?: ^ | \t | \r? \n )
      [^\S\r\n]*                    # leading optional whitespaces
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?:
      (                             # (2 start), Quoted string field
           "
           [^"\\]* 
           (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
           "
           (?:
                [^\S\r\n]*                    # trailing optional whitespaces
                (?= $ | \t | \r? \n )         # Delimiter ahead, tab or newline
           )
      )                             # (2 end)
   |                              # OR
      (                             # (3 start), Non quoted field
           [^\t\r\n]* 
           (?:
                [^\S\r\n]*                    # trailing optional whitespaces 
                (?= $ | \t | \r? \n )         # Delimiter ahead, tab or newline
           )
      )                             # (3 end)
 )
```

Comment: Thank you, I used a block with the ruby #gsub method and it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know ruby, and the solution I'm going to offer is not very nice, but here goes:

Since ruby's implementation of regex doesn't support dynamic width lookbehinds, I couldn't come up with a pattern that matches *only* the `\r\n` you want to remove. But you can replace all matches of this regex pattern

```
(\t"?PROTOCOL[^\t]*)[\r\n]+
```

with `\1` (the text that has been matched by group 1), *until the pattern no longer matches*. Only one substitution won't remove all occurences of `\r\n`. [See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/zD4pV6/1)

I hope you'll find a nicer solution.